# v-model and select multiple

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have the following code in my view:

```
<div class="item_editor_line">
    <label>Artist(s): </label>
    <select multiple
            name="artists[]"
            v-model="artist_ids"
            id="artists">
        <option v-repeat="artists"
                value="@{{ id }}">
                @{{ name }}
        </option>
    </select>
</div>
```

and I populate the `artist_ids` variable with a method called in `ready()`.

When I look at the resultant page though, I see nothing selected in the artists dropdown. `artist_ids` can be confirmed to be correctly populated though, and when I push another id to it in the console, Vue does pick up on this and select all the artists that it should.

What am I doing wrong? How can I get `v-model="artist_ids"` to select from the dropdown appropriately before the page loads?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the built-in `options` attribute to render the options, rather than looping the list with `v-repeat`.  Just make sure your data is formatted appropriately.

Example:

```
data: {
    selected_artists: [ 5678 ],
    artists: [
       { text: 'Some Artist', value: 1234 },
       { text: 'Another Artist', value: 5678 }
    ]
}
```

You can then use the built in options rendering:

```
<select multiple name="artists[]" v-model="selected_artists" options="artists"></select>
```

Here's a codepen which also shows using v-repeat instead:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LpZBom

Comment: Thanks, just saw this. Using an options attribute did indeed simplify things considerably.