# How to make a <md-select> drop down on VueJS Material using data from array?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-material

I've a array and I want put into a `<md-select>` component. On the [offical documentation](https://vuematerial.io/components/select) the list is made from static values.

I'm trying do it:

```
<md-select v-for="item in group" v-bind:key="item">
    <md-option value="{{item.codigo}}"> {{item.nome}} </md-option>
</md-select>

export default {
  data() {
   return {
      group: []
   }
}
```

But it not compiles.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32651715/v-model-and-select-multiple. I think it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to iterate the `<select>` tag and that is incorrect, you should iterate the `<option>` tags, and u need to bind each option value without use `{{ }}`, just using `v-bind` or his shortcut `:` like this:

```html
<md-select v-model="myOptionSelected">
    <md-option 
      v-for="item in group" v-bind:key="item"
      :value="item.codigo"> 
        {{item.nome}} 
    </md-option>
</md-select>

export default {
  data() {
   return {
      myOptionSelected: '',
      group: []
   }
}
```

Comment: Which difference between `v-bind:key` and `value`?

Comment: `v-bind:key` or his shortcut `:key` is the key for each iteration, `value` is the value of the current `option` inside of `select`. Then when u choose some option his value is taken by the `select` on his `v-model`.

Comment: i updated my answer, binding `value` for each option.